# How to differentiate CSS on main pages and subpages?

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie in the middle of making a lovely website. I have now figured out how to get the whole homepage set up with a nice nav bar. Now I would like to start linking to some nice subpages. I have the links set up and everything works but I am very confused about how I separate out the CSS from my main index page to the subpages.

For example, the main page has a jumbotron CSS of a nice palm tree. But I would like a subpage to have the same CSS trick with a bunch of tropical fruit in the background. Then another page to have another background. I feel like I am missing something very basic here but I'm now sure how I separate the CSS from my index page out from my subpages where I'd like to have a different CSS. I'm not even sure of what question to ask as I keep googling things and I'm not getting far.

Basically how do I separate out the design on my main page from my subpages?

```
html { 
  background: url(../images/mexicobeach.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Sansita One', cursive;
  font-size: 82px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
}

h2 {
   font-family: 'Sansita One', cursive;
   font-size: 120px;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 60px 0 0 0;
}

.nav {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left: 0;
  font-family: 'Sansita One', cursive;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

 ul {
      padding: 10px;
      background: rgba(8, 102, 112, 0.5);
    }
    li {
      display: inline;
      padding: 10px 20px 0px 30px;
    }
      a {
      color: white;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mexicostylesheet.css" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Smithies in Mexico</title>
  <style> 
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="subpageabout.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpageschedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpagestay.html">Stay</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpagedo.html">Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpageeat.html">Eat</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpagemexicanmadlibs.html">Mexican Mad Libs</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpagetacogame.html">Taco Game</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpagecountdown.html">Countdown</a></li>
        <li><a href="subpagequiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="jumbotron"
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Smith Ladies Go To</h1>
        <h2>Mexico</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 


</body>
```

Comment: Use different values in the "href" attribute to link another style sheet, in your files,<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourstylesheet">,here you can learn more,http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to take the background out of the html selector and move it to the body selector. Then you would just make multiple classes for the body and call that class on each page.

For example, in your css it could look something like this:

```
body.home {background: url(../images/mexicobeach.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
body.about {background: url(../images/floridabeach.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
body.schedule {background: url(../images/bahamabeach.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Then your HTML on each page would look like this:

```
<body class="home"> for the home page
<body class="about"> for the about page
<body class="schedule"> for the schedule page, etc
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Also, unrelated, you could clean up your heading tags a bit and make it more streamlined by combining the identical attributes and the just separating the size out:
h1, h2 {font-family: 'Sansita One', cursive; text-align: center;   margin: 60px 0 0 0; }
h1 {font-size: 82px;}
h2 {font-size: 120px;}
Then of course, you may want to swap it so the h1 is the large font size since that's typically how they work, h1 is the largest and h6 is the smallest.